# UITest to a page after the face book login

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

I want to test or write some unit tests to some `ExampleViewcontroller`. For example whether the label is existed or not. But we cannot enter this page without login with face book. Now my problem is how can I get the flow to that VC or I will programmatically enter user name and password to face book login page and press the login button (like app.buttons["Log In"].tap), perform login and test whether that label is existed or not in ExampleViewcontroller.

```
func testExample() {
app.decide()
cellTap()

let cell =  app.collectionViews.elementBoundByIndex(1).cells.elementBoundByIndex(0)
waitForElementToAppear(cell, predicate: existsPredicate, seconds: 60)
XCTAssert(cell.exists)
let query:XCUIElementQuery = app.collectionViews.elementBoundByIndex(1).cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).buttons
XCTAssertTrue(query.elementBoundByIndex(2).exists)
let buyNowButton = query.elementBoundByIndex(2)
sleep(2)
buyNowButton.tap()
XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["Login required"].exists)

app.buttons["ConnectWithFacebook"].tap()/*It is button on on alert box on pressing this it will prompt to face book login webview .How to enter user name and password for those fields and press log in button ?*/

app.buttons["Log In"].tap()

}
```

Comment: post your method used for login

Comment: add code in completion of that

Comment: I need in ui test. not in normal unit test